# solidity-coverage show 0% coverage

Tags: solidity

I'm trying to make a test coverage for [MetaCoin](https://github.com/truffle-box/metacoin-box). 
This is my [**package.json**](https://github.com/f0xx0f/testcoverage_metacoin/blob/master/package.json), [**truffle-config.js**](https://github.com/f0xx0f/testcoverage_metacoin/blob/master/truffle-config.js) and
**.solcover.js**:

```
module.exports = {
    port: 8555,
    norpc: true,
    compileCommand: '../node_modules/.bin/truffle compile',
    testCommand: '../node_modules/.bin/truffle test --network coverage'
};
```

I run the commands `./node_modules/.bin/ganache-cli --port 8555 --gasLimit 0xfffffffffff` and `./node_modules/.bin/solidity-coverage` and  the result is an empty test coverage:

```
Generating coverage environment
Running: node --max-old-space-size=4096 ../node_modules/.bin/truffle compile --network coverage
(this can take a few seconds)...
Compiling ./contracts/ConvertLib.sol...
Compiling ./contracts/MetaCoin.sol...
Compiling ./contracts/Migrations.sol...
Writing artifacts to ./build/contracts

Instrumenting  ./coverageEnv/contracts/ConvertLib.sol
Instrumenting  ./coverageEnv/contracts/MetaCoin.sol
Skipping instrumentation of  ./coverageEnv/contracts/Migrations.sol
Running: node --max-old-space-size=4096 ../node_modules/.bin/truffle compile --network coverage
(this can take a few seconds)...
Compiling ./contracts/ConvertLib.sol...
Compiling ./contracts/MetaCoin.sol...
Compiling ./contracts/Migrations.sol...
Writing artifacts to ./build/contracts

Running: node --max-old-space-size=4096 ../node_modules/.bin/truffle test --network coverage
(this can take a few seconds)...
Using network 'coverage'.

Compiling ./test/TestMetacoin.sol...


  TestMetacoin
    ✓ testInitialBalanceUsingDeployedContract (89ms)
    ✓ testInitialBalanceWithNewMetaCoin (85ms)

  Contract: MetaCoin
    ✓ should put 10000 MetaCoin in the first account
    ✓ should call a function that depends on a linked library (54ms)
    ✓ should send coin correctly (128ms)


  5 passing (8s)

-----------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------------|
File             |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines |Uncovered Lines |
-----------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------------|
 contracts/      |        0 |        0 |        0 |        0 |                |
  ConvertLib.sol |        0 |      100 |        0 |        0 |              6 |
  MetaCoin.sol   |        0 |        0 |        0 |        0 |... 23,24,28,32 |
-----------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------------|
All files        |        0 |        0 |        0 |        0 |                |
-----------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------------|

Istanbul coverage reports generated
Cleaning up...
Done.
```

I get the same result if I check without tests .

Maybe I'm doing something wrong. Please help me.

Comment: Could you share the contents of your .solcover.js file?

Comment: could you show your test file code? Inferring from the test descriptions, it looks like you do a lot of checks on balances, but might not be calling many functions. Sending funds and checking balances doesn't traverse or tickle your code. You'd need to be calling functions that execute your code in your contracts, which is what coverage measures. that's assuming you still care. It's been a while :-p